# C# Selenium ChromeDriver: Google Chrome fails when run as administrator

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have encountered an usual situation when using Selenium Web Driver C# with Chrome: if the process running the tests is "run as administrator" (Visual Studio or `nunit3-console.exe`) Chrome will fail to load.

**Context**

- OS: Windows 7 x64
- Chrome: Version 64.0.3282.167 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver (chromedriver.exe): 2.35.0
- Local policy does not allow chrome extensions

**Steps**

1. Start a test that also initializes the driver

   ```
   var options = new ChromeOptions();

   //TODO: check if really needed
   options.AddAdditionalCapability("useAutomationExtension", false);
   options.AddArguments("--allow-no-sandbox-job");
   options.AddArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");

   var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
   ```
2. ChromeDriver starts successfully:

   ```
   Starting ChromeDriver 2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73) on
   port 61771
   Only local connections are allowed.

   DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12890/devtools/browser/e50864bd-9c30-445c-a3f8-e33d6b6e5b49
   ```
3. Chrome is opened, but the tab fails to load

[image: chrome failed tab]

4. If I refresh the tab when being attached, I receive the following exception information:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: session not created exception
>
> from tab crashed
>
> (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.167)
>
> (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528161
>   (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73),platform=Windows NT
>   6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (InsecureCertificate)

I can't figure why it is failing. I feel that it might be connected [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=167556), but the issue deals with another user, not the same user in elevated mode.

**Question:** Why C# Selenium ChromeDriver + Chrome fail when run as administrator. How can I investigate the root cause for this?

---

I have created a small Console Application as suggested in the comments:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var options = new ChromeOptions();
    // this is required since otherwise it will try to load some extension which is not allowed by local policy
    options.AddAdditionalCapability("useAutomationExtension", false);
    // try to catch some errors, but does not seem to work
    options.AddArguments("--enable-logging");
    options.AddArguments("--v=1");
    var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost");
}
```

---

Did some testing on another computer outside of the company and it works correctly regardless of Chrome Driver (tried both 2.35 and 2.36). Other difference would be the operating system (Windows 7 at work and Windows 10 at home) and the local policy at work (which might affect Chrome settings).

---

Thanks to `Tarun Lalwani` I reduced the problem to what seems to be related to Run as admin + local policy + possible Chrome issue:

1. running Web driver in verbose mode indicated that Chrome uses a completely different profile path when run normally vs. run as admin:

   - Run normally: `dir="C:\Users\<my-dos-profile-name>\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir21000_25907"` (changes for each run)
   - Run as admin: `dir="C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\scoped_dir7236_26307"`
2. Inspecting `chrome.debug` file within Chrome's installation folder (there is also a debug file created within each temporary profile) I see these errors:

> [0303/120050.213:ERROR:process_reader_win.cc(151)] SuspendThread:
>   Access is denied. (0x5) 
>   [0303/120050.214:ERROR:process_reader_win.cc(123)] NtOpenThread:
>   {Access Denied} A process has requested access to an object, but has
>   not been granted those access rights. (0xc0000022) 
>   [0303/120050.215:ERROR:exception_snapshot_win.cc(88)] thread ID 13672
>   not found in process 
>   [0303/120050.215:WARNING:crash_report_exception_handler.cc(62)]
>   ProcessSnapshotWin::Initialize failed

3. If I simply run Chrome as admin, all restore tabs are crashing and I obtain similar errors in the log. Console (cmd) output says:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application>[7244:16744:0303/125934.383:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1009)]
>   Lost UI shared context. 
>   [7244:13716:0303/125956.057:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(381)]
>   Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -118

So, at least now I know it is related to Chrome starting as admin and not related to Chrome driver.

Comment: Have you researched this from the basis that it might be a cert issue?  Googling "chrome InsecureCertificate" turned up quite a few interesting links, but frankly they're mostly over my head.

Comment: @BillHileman - `--ignore-certificate-errors` should take of certificate issues. Anyway, this is happening even if I run selenium against an web site hosted in localhost (http connection), so I doubt the issue is certificate related.

Comment: @BillHileman - another interesting aspect is that it works fine with Firefox. Also, I noticed that Chrome (and other browsers do not) fails to work if "ran as another user", so I sense it might be connected to the way it handles the profile data.

Comment: It would appear that the issue you linked to has been a problem since 2012 and never resolved, at least according to one comment there.  I wish I could offer some help.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue in a simple console application without nunit? Try to increase the log level to see if the reason is logged (https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging).

Comment: @FlorentB. - yes, I created a repro and included in my OP. I was not able to record anything useful in Chrome's debug log, but driver's logging provided some useful information. I was able to circumvent the issue (also provided an answer), but I am not happy with the solution. At least I am not stuck anymore and it might help others in the future. Thanks.

Comment: @Alexei, instead of chromedriver `2.35`, i used `2.36` and it worked. Can you check upgrading?

Comment: @TarunLalwani - can you please indicate the download source for 2.36? [Chrome driver downloads](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) stop at 2.36 and this is also true for NuGet package manager (latest build for package Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver is 2.35.

Comment: I used this in my `packages.config` `<package id="Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" version="2.36.0" targetFramework="net461" />`

Comment: @TarunLalwani - indeed 2.36 did not show up for net452, but showed for 461. Anyway, I have tested the original code (net452. driver 2.35) on another machine (Windows 10 instead of Windows 7 and no company policy applied) and it works regardless of chrome driver version. So, I feel some local security settings are messing with Chrome.

Comment: @TarunLalwani - also, 2.36 fails exactly as 2.35 within my original setup (Windows 7, local policy applied by company).

Comment: Can you check in windows event viewer if there is any logging of an error when this happens?

Comment: @TarunLalwani - cannot find anything there. Also, Chrome does not write anything related to this within its debug file (`--enable-logging` with `--v=1`).

Comment: @Alexei, if the issue is the location of the profile, you can change it by overriding the temp folder before launching the driver: `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TMP", "C:\\TEMP");`

Comment: @FlorentB. - yes, it is an option. However, I found out that I can use an elevated client as long as the driver is not run as admin (which in turn will run Chrome in non-elevated mode). Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I managed to bypass this issue using `--no-sandbox` options. While it works in my case, I am not happy with the solution [since no-sandbox is not a recommended option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68832/what-does-the-chromium-option-no-sandbox-mean).

My final minimal working code:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Driver, LogLevel.All);
options.AddAdditionalCapability("useAutomationExtension", false);
options.AddArguments("--no-sandbox");
var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost");
```

`SetLoggingPreference` is not part of the solution, but it provided helpful in trying `no-sandbox` option. Web driver threw the following error when Chrome tab crashed:

> [17532:18272:0301/225923.296:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1009)]
>   Lost UI shared context.

---

After digging more I found a simple and decent solution: start `chromedriver.exe` without elevation and connect to it using `RemoteWebDriver` instead of `ChromeDriver` (thanks to `Tarun Lalwani` for pointing out this pattern):

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Driver, LogLevel.All);
options.AddAdditionalCapability("useAutomationExtension", false);
var driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:9515"), options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost");
```