# QWebEngineView not loading with default Windows elevation

Tags: python, windows, pyqt5, python-3.9, qwebengineview

I'm having a bizarre issue where this simple QWebEngine code runs perfectly fine as a regular user on Windows 10 (loads the page fully), but when I elevate my own default user account it stops loading the page. The progress output will go from 0->100 and not call loadFinished on the browser or show any output on the page. I've tried running it as an elevated standard Administrator built-in account and it seemed to work oddly enough.

Here's the unloaded page:

[image: Here's the unloaded page]

and here's it working properly:

[image: here's it working properly]

Running with `os.environ["QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS"] = "1"` doesn't show any discrepancies between the elevated and non-elevated processes.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl('https://www.google.com'))
        self.browser.loadProgress.connect(self.on_load_progress)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
        self.show()

    def on_load_progress(self, progress: int):
        print(f'loading progress:[{progress}]...')


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main_win = MainWindow()

app.exec()
```

Comment: Quick update: after hooking into the QWebEngineView.renderProcessTerminated signal I discovered that the render process keeps getting killed before [0] and also before [100] load progress of the page.

Answer (score 0):

After trying many things and going through many logs, the only partial solution I've found to this problem is adding `--no-sandbox` to the QApplication argument list to make the Chromium webdriver work at all. For my app this is enough but running without sandboxing is less than ideal for a broader solution.

For those interested I found the answer thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48811713/c-sharp-selenium-chromedriver-google-chrome-fails-when-run-as-administrator) thread (has a lot more relevant info than my descriptions).